# Writing to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, d3.js

I need help with my json output. At present my output is as so:

```
[
  [
    {
        "ING_SW_CB": "5",
        "SB_SW_CB": "3",
        "NG3_SW_CB": "1",
        "Mould_Close": "4",
        "Leak_Test": "5",
        "ML_Load": "6",
        "Pre_Heat": "3",
        "Dispense": "9",
        "A310": "7",
        ............
    }
  ]
]
```

I’d like it to be as following with "key" & "value" included in the output.

```
{"key":"ING_SW_CB", "value": "5"},
{"key":"SB_SW_CB", "value": "3"},
 ..............................
```

Hers is my PHP script:

```
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['ING_SW_CB'] = $row['ING_SW_CB'];
    $row_array['SB_SW_CB'] = $row['SB_SW_CB'];
    $row_array['NG3_SW_CB'] = $row['NG3_SW_CB'];
    $row_array['Mould_Close'] = $row['Mould_Close'];
    $row_array['Leak_Test'] = $row['Leak_Test'];
    $row_array['ML_Load'] = $row['ML_Load'];
    $row_array['Pre_Heat'] = $row['Pre_Heat'];
    $row_array['Dispense'] = $row['Dispense'];
    $row_array['A310'] = $row['A310'];
    $row_array['Gelation'] = $row['Gelation'];
    $row_array['Platen'] = $row['Platen'];
    $row_array['Mainline_Unload'] = $row['Mainline_Unload'];
    $row_array['De_mould'] = $row['De_mould'];
    $row_array['Clean_Up'] = $row['Clean_Up'];
    $row_array['Soda_Blast'] = $row['Soda_Blast'];
    $row_array['Miscellaneous'] = $row['Miscellaneous'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}

$json_data = json_encode($json_response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
file_put_contents('your_json_file.json', $json_data);
```

I need the keywords "key" & "value" added to the output so I can popuate a D3 chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop on the row's results and build more arrays:

```
while(...) {
   $temp = array();
   foreach($row as $key => $value) {
       $temp[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
   }
   $json_response[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, I'm off to give this a whirl !

Comment: For some reason Marc the 'your_json_file.json' is not created. I don't get an error querying but the file is not written.

Comment: check the return value of file_put_contents. if it's boolean false, then there's something wrong.

Comment: Thank you Marc, this done it for me! I left out a ) in my while loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the columns:

```
$json_response = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $json_row = array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $json_row[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
    }
    $json_response[] = $json_row;
}
$json_data = json_encode($json_response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('your_json_file.json', $json_data);
```

Comment: Thank yo Barmar, I'm going to alter the code and I'll let you know how I get on, cheers.

Comment: For some reason Barmar the 'your_json_file.json' is not created. I don't get an error querying but the file is not written.

Comment: Maybe you don't have write permission to the folder. Check your PHP error log for the details.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I think there should be an extra ) in the while loop. When I add this the file 'your_json_file.json' is now created but it contains an empty array as following.                                                                                             [
    []
]

Comment: I had a couple of other errors: `$col` should have been `$row` (didn't you get an Undefined Variable warning for that?), and `MYSQL_ASSOC` should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC` (I copied that error from your question).

Comment: Thanks Barmar, It's perfect now. I'm getting the result I needed. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


//push the values in the array

 foreach($row as $k=>$v){
      $my_array = array("key"=>$k, "value"=>$v);
 }

   array_push($json_response,$my_array);
}



 $json_data = json_encode($json_response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
 file_put_contents('your_json_file.json', $json_data);
```

Comment: You're missing the `key` and `value` properties.

Comment: And you're overwriting `$my_array` each time through the inner loop.

Comment: Hi MrTechie, when I use your method, what is returned for me is all the "Miscellaneous" coulumns with their values. The other columns aren't shown in my external json file.